# how can I connect MySQL with Android Project using MySQL JDBC driver?

Tags: android

I want to get data from table in MySQL and to show it in TextView, but I have some problems when I try to connect with database. I'm using Eclipse for Android, and when I try to get data from MySQL in Java Project it works, but when I use Android Project it doesn't work. Does anyone know Or to give me other advice how to connect Android Project with MySQL?I m getting the error in the android emulator that java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Comment: Please post the logcat output of your error and a relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases android apps do not connect directly to a database, as this means you have to store and expose connection information right in your app.

You should implement a web service that allows interaction with your database.

There are rare cases when a direct connection to a MySQL server makes sense, e.g. if you are writing query tool or MySQL server management tool.