# How to populate online mysql database data in android listview?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from online mysql database host "freesqldatabase.com" and display it in listview in android. here is my code

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:mysql://sql4.freesqldatabase.com/sql428447", 
               username, pass);
}
```

This is how I am trying to connect to the database which is working exactly perfect in simple java code but if I try to use same in mainactivity.java of android application it isn't. It is not even throwing any exception nor any error. I have tried to test it by just displaying few toast texts after this code which is not getting displayed so I guess there must be a problem in the code above for android?

Comment: "_if I try to use same in mainactivity.java of android application it isnt_" What exactly does it do?

Comment: it means i have tries the same code in some other java program. but if i use same code for same purpose in java file of android application then it is somehow not connecting to the online database

Comment: So it throws no exceptions or errors, it just simply doesn't connect?

Comment: You say you know this because your toasts didn't display, but maybe you just had a problem with the toasts themselves. Show the code you used to test if your connection was made.

Comment: no man they are getting displayed before this code but not after this one so what must be the case?

Comment: I am trying to fire just simple query to select * from table just to check if it is flowing smoothly but it is not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46454/discussion-between-subodh-mankar-and-takendarkk)

Comment: Just check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926705/how-can-i-connect-mysql-with-android-project-using-mysql-jdbc-driver) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936312/how-to-connect-android-to-mysql-database-server). The problem is that you can't connect to MySQL in the way you are trying.

Comment: thanks mate let me have some time